# Removing Markers in Google Maps API v3 JS

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

I have this code in javascript and html, everything works perfectly but i tried many way to remove markers in google maps. Help me, thank you !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize() {
    var markers = [
      {
          "title": 'ABC',
          "lat": '19.1759668',
          "lng": '72.79504659999998',
          "description": 'ZXVZXV'
      },
      {
          "title": 'ASDASD',
          "lat": '19.0883595',
          "lng": '72.82652380000002',
          "description": 'ZXVZXA.'
      },
      ];
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 25,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.1759668, 72.79504659999998),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
        });

    }
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: How are you trying to remove markers? My question would be, if you don't want a marker  to appear, don't add it to the map, so I assume there is some reason to remove the markers and/or mechanism for doing so that you haven't explained to us.  Please provide a [mcve] that shows what you have tried that you thought should work that didn't.

Comment: I wanna add show/hide button into map. But i tried many way and didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use top window  array of markersObject eg markersObj  store the markers object inside and then looping for set null or set map

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var markersObj = [];
  var map;

   function initialize() {
    var markers = [
      {
          "title": 'ABC',
          "lat": '19.1759668',
          "lng": '72.79504659999998',
          "description": 'ZXVZXV'
      },
      {
          "title": 'ASDASD',
          "lat": '19.0883595',
          "lng": '72.82652380000002',
          "description": 'ZXVZXA.'
      },
      ];
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 25,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.1759668, 72.79504659999998),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
        });

        markersObj.push(marker); 

    }
   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


   function hideMarkers() {
      nElem =  markersObj.length
      for (i=0; i< nElem; i++){
        markersObj[i].setMap(null);
      }

   }


   function showMarkers() {
      nElem =  markersObj.length
      for (i=0; i< nElem; i++){
        markersObj[i].setMap(map);
      }

   }


    ....
```

You need two  buttons that call hideMarkers or showMarkers   respectively